# Alcoholic behavior at a bar without having any alcohol?

Tags: alcohol

I am a recovering alcoholic sober 11 month.  I do not crave alcohol, or need it anymore. I have adapted skills that I am no longer depressed. but enjoying life again.fun, happy, with good social skills.  I have treated myself to a month in Mexico were I have vacationed over 20 years drunk at beachside bars.  This first week, I headed to the first bar with a big party crowd.  I have met 15+ people of what I used to be like.  After 3 day same time they are all drunk and acting crazy.  By the time I left all 3 days I could swear I was drunk, lost all inhabitions, over talkative Without any alcohol. Any still no craving.???

Answer (score 0):

See the placebo effect, it's been known to work in situations right up to double blind studies on *dogs*. Very weird.

Also, I would guess you would consider yourself a people pleaser? I forget the name of it but there's a phenomenon whereby individuals begin to imitate their cohort (mirroring?, Stockholm effect?)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I wish a few more people would have attempted their thoughts.  I'm currently in Mexico on an extended vacation but would like to study this more at a later date.